# Codeigniter, page linking redirect me to dashboard instead of controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

First of all sorry if this question is so basic, i was just started to learn using codeigniter and web development :)

So i have this code in my home views that was supposed to redirect me to login page

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="Login">Login</a>
        </li>
```

and this one is the controller located at application/controllers/ that supposed to open login views

```
<?php class Login extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->model('m_login');

}

function index(){
    $this->load->view('v_login');
}
function aksi_login(){      
}
}    
function logout(){      
}
}
```

but whenever i try click the login link it always direct me to xampp dashboard, i have tried using `href="<?php echo site_url('controllers/Login') ?>"` and still no changes is there something i can do to fix this? thanks a lot

.htaccess if needed

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use controller words inside site_url() function

proper way to indicate any route is

```
 <a href="<?php site_url('Login'); ?>">Go To Login</a>
```

here Login is a controller. This will go to index() as default. if you want to go to other method then just modify the above code like below

```
<a href="<?php site_url('Login/logout'); //will go to logout method ?>">Go To Login</a>

<a href="<?php site_url('Login/registration'); //will go to registration method ?>">Go To Login</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it doesnt direct me to dashboard anymore using this code, but instead it keep reloading the home page and not redirected me to any page